# Splitting a double in two, C#

Tags: c#

I'm attempting to use a double to represent a bit of a dual-value type in a database that must sometimes accept two values, and sometimes accept only one (int).

So the field is a float in the database, and in my C# code, it is a double (since mapping it via EF makes it a double for some reason... )

So basically what I want to do .. let's say 2.5 is the value. I want to separate that out into 2, and 5. Is there any implicit way to go about this?

Comment: Why are you attempting that instead of just using two columns?

Comment: It is a little difficult to explain... But basically the data given may or may not be distributed between two columns, and it is impossible to determine it at database level. It is dynamic every time the data is used.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like this:

```
int intPart = (int)value;
double fractionalPart = value - intPart;
```

If you want `fractionalPart` to be an `int`, you can multiply it by 10<sup>n</sup>, where `n` is the number of digits you want, and cast to `int`.
However, beware of precision loss.

However, this is *extremely* poor design; you should probably make two fields.

SQL Server's `float` type is an 8-byte floating-point value, equivalent to C#'s `double`.

Comment: @Simon:  That's a bad idea. How many significant digits?  What about `2.5`, `2.05`, `2.50`?  If you always want one digit, multiply by `10` and cast to int.  However, beware of precision.

Comment: What about converting to string and splitting at the "."? This would of course imply that he saves it as string

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to implicitly type-cast the double to an int to get the first part and subtract that from the number and multiply that by ten to get the second part